# NDB Query using IN order by greatest matches

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a model with a query:

```
class Words (ndb.Model):
    word = ndb.StringProperty ()
    key = ndb.KeyProperty ("OtherModel")
    count = ndb.IntegerProperty ()

    @classmethod
    def query_words (cls, words):
         return cls.query (cls.word.IN (words)).order (cls.count, cls.key)
```

This isn't really what I want. I'd like to able order by the number of matches i.e. the number of times key actually is in the result set; if there were four words in the list words and there was a key result for each of the words I'd like that first.

The model is essentially a frequency tablation of words in the model that is represented by key (OtherModel in my example).

TIA.

Comment: What you ask is not possible with datastore queries. Order can only be determined by a predefined dictionary.  You should probably look at using cloudsql, or re-order in memory.

Comment: Thanks Tim. In memory it is.